# Tint of a built-in UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

Is there any way to change the tint of BUILT-IN toolbar in viewcontroller class (not the one that I created). (I know we can set the toolbar items but I couldn't figure out how to modify appearance).

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can just set the toolbar's `tintColor` property. It takes a `UIColor` object.

Comment: `UIViewController` does not have a "built in" toolbar. Check the documentation. If you want one, you're going to have to create it and add it to the view yourself.

Comment: but you can set the toolbar items so there shoud be. Check the doc there is a method called setToolbarItems in UIViewController.

Comment: Yes I see that. The documenation also states that the `toolbarItems` property works in conjunction with UINavigationController. If the view controller is embedded into a UINavigationController and that navigation controller has a toolbar, then these items will be displayed on the toolbar.

Comment: ok so I should access like this and it worked: self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [tintColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIToolbar/tintColor) in Interface Builder, or in code like so:

```
toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.83 green:0.43 blue:0.57 alpha:0.5];
```